# How to i upload a file containing AWS secret keys to Heroku?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I need to upload file containing secret keys to Heroku. AWS needs to have the file on the server i use for it to be able to work.

So how i do i upload a file? I do not think it can be in the / of my project. Right now i have it in /user, on my macbook.

Comment: Wouldn't IAM roles work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure Heroku allows to store files (it has an ephemeral file storage).

The approach to store keys (and env settings) is to use Config Vars: they are defined by you as key-value (ie AWS_KEY:123) and injected into your app runtime where you can obtain them as env variables, in Java for example

```
System.getenv("AWS_KEY");
```